# How to make a GUID column in Orchard's migrations?

Tags: c#, sql-server, orchardcms, database-migration, orchardcms-1.8

I can make a `GUID` column through ArcGIS and I can make `uniqueidentifier` column in SQLSqrver, but Orchard wants to autogenerate the table through `migrations.cs`. Unfortunately, the `GUID` column make migration fail, no table is created. I tried to decorate the column in the model with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]`, but it didn't help. Am I using it wrong? Or do I need something different? I make several other tables, so I would prefer to avoid bigger changes outside the `GUID` column unless necessary.

**Migrations.cs** (important parts):

```
public int Create() {

    SchemaBuilder.CreateTable(typeof(FooRecord).Name,
        table => table
            .Column<int>("Id", column => column.PrimaryKey().Identity())
            .Column<Guid>("GUID", column => column.NotNull().Unique())
            //other columns
        );

    return 1;
}
```

**Model**:

```
public class FooRecord
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public virtual Guid GUID { get; set; }
    //other columns
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Orchard previously didn't support that syntax for guids last I checked (a few years ago) and you had to write it like this:

```
.Column("MyGuid", DbType.Guid, column => column.NotNull().Unique())
```

Comment: Works! I'll wait with the bounty assignment an hour or two and unless some other, even better answer (unlikely!) comes though.

Comment: Cool, was it the column name or the syntax that fixed it? Or both?

Comment: Syntax; though I changed the column name as well and didn't any risk hidden bugs coming from it. Btw. I'll have to wait with the bounty bit longer, but you have it reserved :-)

Comment: I quickly checked and you can have a column called guid :)